Databricks Optimize - Zorder command is taking too long
I wrote a DataFrame into a Delta table (e.g., demo_table) using the overwrite mode, which involves dropping the table beforehand. After the write operation was successful, I executed the OPTIMIZE command on the table. However, the OPTIMIZE operation took nearly an hour to complete. How can I improve this process?
Note : The table is in a partitioned format.
Command : OPTIMIZE  schema.demo_table ZORDER BY (custom_id,sales_date)
Note : custom_id : Generated new columns , when we create final df
final record count would be 3 million records. Not a wider table. Schema have basic data types . integer,string. there is no complex data types.
Observation : when i use existing column in Zorder , it executed  within 5 min.

Are you using Azure databricks?

we configured with aws s3 as source

Hi, can you provide more details of the table for example schema, table size and partitioned columns?

updated my questions
